# What exactly do the BOT Community when modified some questions in the main site of AI.SE?

Tags: discussion

I always see a BOT Community modified questions for example this: "modified 2 hours ago"

[image]

[Is the emergence of the field "psychology of artificial intelligence" necessary?](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/8523/is-the-emergence-of-the-field-psychology-of-artificial-intelligence-necessary)

When I open the question I not find what exactly modified the bot so what is the purpose of the BOT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click on the "Show activity on this post" button (in red in the screenshot below)

[image]

You should see the activity of the post.

For example, if you click on that button of [this post](https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/10053/2444), you should see this

[image]

The purpose of the bot is partially suggested in the message written by the same

> This question has **answers that may be good or bad**; the system has marked it active so that they **can be reviewed**.

So, the bot bumps posts that, for example, do not have an accepted answer or have answers but without votes so that people can review the answers and assess their quality.

You have more info about this bot [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/412121/3924118).